# How do I replace an HTML background image correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to simply replace the background of an HTML tag and have it fill the screen.

This is my code which works to fill the screen when the page loads:

```
html { 
  background: url(1000x800.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I have some code in JQuery which listens for the page to scroll and then tries to replace the image which is this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        // when the scroll reaches the bottom
       if($(document).scrollTop() >= new_height) {
          new_height = $(document).scrollTop() + 10; 
          // change the background
          $('html').css({background: "url(1000x800_2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed"}); 
       }

     }); // end of window scroll
```

The image does get replaced and it is centered and fixed. However, it does not fill the screen. It stays at 1000x800.(My screen size is 1900x1000).

It seems like the "background-size: cover" property is lost in the process. So I tried to reinstate that and I get a javascript error using this code:

```
$('html').css({background-size: "cover"});
```

Does anyone know how to make this work correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Change that to `.css({backgroundSize: "cover"})`. The error occurs because hyphens are not valid variable characters in JS.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Why the difference from css to jquery?

Comment: It's because the `-` is not valid in JS variable names. You need to either quote it: `'background-size'` or use the native JS CSS property: `backgroundSize`.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I didn't think to use quotes since 'background' didn't need them. Also, I wasn't aware of the whole hypen thing in JS.

Comment: Post as answer, so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

`background` is a shortcut property. If you don't supply *all* parameters, any not supplied will be reset to their default. As you are only changing the background image, use `background-image`:

```
$('html').css({ 'background-image': 'url(1000x800_2.jpg)' });
```

Comment: Tried that. Still no joy. Thanks though.

Comment: This should work. Can you add a working demo of the issue in something like http://jsfiddle.net to your question.

Comment: Did you put quotes around `'background-image'`?

Comment: By your own reasoning, the cover attribute should be lost since it is not redefined. That was my problem all along. I had to re-issue the "cover" attribute to the background size. So leaving it off, messed me up.

Comment: That's right, but if you use `background-image`  you won't have to redefine it.